# (Java) Error: This method must return a result of type int

Tags: java

public class SingelNumber {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numList = {1,1,2,2,3,1,7,3};
    System.out.print(singleNumber(numList));

}
public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) {

        boolean dup = false;
        int check = 0;

        for (int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            check =nums[i];
            for (int j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++){
                if (check==nums[j])
                    dup = true;
                    break;
            }

            }
        if (dup==false)
            return check;     
    }
 }
```

I got an error "This method must return a result of type int". I don't know why since variable check is an int.

Comment: if neither of the `if` check pass, what would the method return

Comment: If `dup` is true then you have no return value. Also don't explicitly check boolean values in your conditions, its already a boolean. Use instead `if(!dup)`

Comment: You only return an `int` under certain conditions.  Under other conditions you return nothing at all.  Fix your code formatting, which will help you to see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is confused what to do if dup is true, you should add else statement to:

```
if (dup==false)
        return check;  
else return 0;
```

You should install an IDE (like intelliJ), so it would point out your mistakes right away.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your function only returns check if dup is false. If dup was true, it will return undefined.